# CSS buttons overlapping

Tags: css, button

I have looked at the other questions about this and none of the solutions work. I have a vertical navBar that is supposed to hold buttons, which are also links, and they work fine when they are the default width but when I change the size all the buttons overlap and the only one that shows up is the last one.

Relevant CSS code:

```
.navBar{
 background-color: #180639;
 width: 20%;
 color: #B6AFC1;
 text-align: center;
 border: 1px solid #B6AFC1;
 font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;
 font-size: 40px;
 left: 0px;
 position: absolute;
 overflow: visible;
}
button.navBar{
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color: #675AFD;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

Relevant HTML:

```
<div class="navBar">
      <a href="/"><button type="button" class="navBar">Home</button></a>
      <a href="/chat"><button type="button" class="navBar">Community</button></a>
      <a href="/events"><button type="button" class="navBar">Events</button></a>
      <a href="/prideprom"><button type="button" class="navBar" class="navBar">Pride Prom</button></a>
      <a href="/rights"><button type="button" class="navBar">Resources</button></a>
      <a href="/funds"><button type="button" class="navBar">Fundraising</button></a>
        <a href="/profile/TrueTransRebel"><button type="button" class="navBar">current_user.username</button></a>
        <a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out"><button type="button" class="navBar" class="navBar">Log Out</button></a>
</div>
```

I am writing this using Ruby on Rails if that helps anyone come up with a solution. Sorry if the code is messy, I have been looking at a lot of solutions and adding a bunch of random stuff in just trying to force it to work. I should also note the end goal is for all the buttons to line up in a column

[This is what it looks like presently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cw7UV.png)

Comment: You should create an example page for us, so we can see what your problem is. Obviously if you set your buttons width to like 100px, but the 20% width is only 100 pixels (assuming 100% is 500 pixels), you can only view one of the buttons, as they will overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's causing the problem here is that you are applying the `position:absolute` property to both the navbar `<div>` *and* the `<button>`s. You should separate the classes to apply separate styling to each, independently:

HTML: (note that I changed the classnames for the `<button>`s to `navBar_button`

```
<div class="navBar">
  <a href="/"><button type="button" class="navBar_button">Home</button></a>
  <a href="/chat"><button type="button" class="navBar_button">Community</button></a>
  <a href="/events"><button type="button" class="navBar_button">Events</button></a>
  <a href="/prideprom"><button type="button" class="navBar_button">Pride Prom</button></a>
  <a href="/rights"><button type="button" class="navBar_button">Resources</button></a>
  <a href="/funds"><button type="button" class="navBar_button">Fundraising</button></a>
  <a href="/profile/TrueTransRebel"><button type="button" class="navBar_button">current_user.username</button></a>
  <a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out"><button type="button" class="navBar_button" class="navBar">Log Out</button></a>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.navBar {
 background-color: #180639;
 width: 20%;
 color: #B6AFC1;
 text-align: center;
 border: 1px solid #B6AFC1;
 font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;
 font-size: 40px;
 left: 0px;
 position: absolute;
 overflow: visible;
}
.navBar_button {
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color: #675AFD;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Also keep in mind that you don't need the `float:left` if you have the `display:inline-block` for the buttons, you can use one or the other. And your `navBar` div is only 20% width, so these elements will essentially stack on top of each other. If you expand that width to 100%, they will then be next to each other along the top.